# Error handling in cffile "write" action

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Wondering if there is a possibility to handle errors which may occur during file "write" action.

I've found nothing on Adobe's Coldfusion website or by googling.

Can one simply write something like

```
<cffile action="write" file="#filename#" output="#trim(content)#" />
```

without error handling? Is it safe?

Comment: File operation are never safe since the operating system is in charge of handling writes to the disk. Permissions could fail, a file lock could be in place, the disk could be full etc. Use `try/catch` as already suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course you should use error handling. ColdFusion has try/catch like any other language. [Read the documentation on the cftry tag here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ec6.html).

You can at least wrap that code in a try/catch block like this:

```
<cftry>
    <cffile action="write" file="#filename#" output="#trim(content)#" />
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <!--- do what is needed here to handle the error --->
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

But you should also be using some overall error handling as well. [Read about overall error handling in ColdFusion here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/handling-errors/about-error-handling-in-coldfusion.html).

*I have updated the error handling link to the latest ColdFusion documentation but be aware that this question was related to ColdFusion 9 so there may be some changes that do not apply. I will include the original documentation link that I had in case this 404 error is only temporary. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0bb9b-7ffe.html (this original link is now throwing a 404 error)*

Comment: @topshot thanks, I updated the link to the latest documentation even though the original question was for ColdFusion 9.